# Can we use 'else unless' in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby we can do things like

```
unless something
  do_this
else 
  do_that 
end
```

We can also write else if

```
unless something
 do_that
elsif something_else
 do_this 
end
```

But can we write something like

```
if something
 do_this
else unless something_else
 do_that
end
```

Of course the simple solution would be to use the `!` operator.

Comment: how about `elsif !somethingelse`?

Comment: In general, avoid `unless` unless (:p) you have only the main clause. It's confusing with a simple `else`, yet alone `elsunless`.

Comment: I completely agree with you :) I was just being curious.. in most cases I use it only in a postfix form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In that case, you need another level of nesting.

```
if something
  ...
else
  unless something_else
    ...
  end
end
```

The reason is probably that `else` + `unless` is too complicated.